# Unique e-mail address registraton code not working as expected | encode_decode issue?

Tags: codeigniter, validation, utf-8, callback, php

I'm working on a user registration form. I am trying to make it so that users must have an email address that is not already registered in the system.

I believe that the `is_unique` function is not working because all of the email address data is being stored in a Base64 encoded format and the query is being submitted in an un-encoded format.

I have tried tweaking things in my controller and model where it seemed appropriate, but I end up with errors.

Here is the function from my **CONTROLLER:**

```
function check_physician_email($physician_email){

    $physician_email_check=$this->model_site->get_single_record( 'physicians', 'email', $physician_email );

    if($physician_email_check){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_physician_email', 'The %s is already taken!');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Using this **MODEL:**

```
function get_single_record( $table_name, $primary_key_name, $primary_key_val ) {  //get a record with a given condition from table

    $query = $this->db->get_where($table_name, array( $primary_key_name => $primary_key_val));

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

} //end get_single_record
```

When that didn't work I started pointing it at `get_email_record` and have tried a few variations of the following in my **MODEL:**

```
function get_email_record( $table_name, $primary_key_name, $primary_key_val ) {  //get a record with a given condition from table

    $query = $this->db->get_where('physicians', array( encode_decode($_REQUEST['email'], 'decode') => $primary_key_val));


    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

} //end get_email_record
```

That just leads to an **`encode_decode error`**:

```
Error Number: 1300  
Invalid utf8 character string: '\xB2\xB6\xACr\x19\xDA\xB5\xB8\xA8r\x8A\xE9r\x89'
SELECT * FROM (`physicians`) WHERE `²¶¬rÚµ¸¨rŠér‰` = 'user@email.com'
Filename: /usr/sites/phototherapydoctor.com/www/html/models/model_site.php
Line Number: 92
```

And if I do this in my **MODEL:**

```
function get_email_record( $table_name, $primary_key_name, $primary_key_val ) {  //get a record with a given condition from table

    $query = $this->db->get_where('physicians', array( 'email' => encode_decode($_REQUEST[$primary_key_val],'encode')));


    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

} //end get_email_record
```

I get this **`Undefined index error`**:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: user@email.com
Filename: models/model_site.php
Line Number: 92
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the callback that I can see? You need this in your form validation rules.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','callback_physician_email_check');
```

Comment: Yes, it is in there, I just didn't want to post it seeing as I had already posted so much. But, I am sure that it is set right. I have others working fine in other places. This is the only one giving me any trouble.

Comment: To ensure it's working comment out any code other than the return false in the callback. That way you'll know the callback itself is working and you can continue the process of elimination.

Comment: The callback is confirmed to be working is terms of the return false. Once the rest of the code is uncommented it continues to NOT work. I've also continued to try other variations of the same thing. No luck.